# What are .jazzignore files?

Tags: eclipse, rtc, jazz

I see .jazzignore files in my eclipse and I know I am using RTC, but I know neither of them. Can any one explain what does it actually mean ?

Answer (score 5):

A .jazzignore will make sure the files listed in that .jazzignore file will ***not*** be listed as "unresolved".

The modifications on those files will be ignored.

See more at the [official RTC help page](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_scm_eclipse_ignore.html)

> Eclipse workspaces often include files or folders, such as compiler output, log files, and so on, that you do not want to place under source control.
>   You can specify resources or classes of resources to be ignored by Rational Team Concert™ source control. Ignored resources are never checked in.
>
> A `.jazzignore` file is used to prevent items from being checked into change sets.
>   A `.jazzignore` file consists of a series of patterns. Any file, folder, or symbolic link whose name matches a pattern cannot be committed to a change set.
>
> There are two types of patterns in a .jazzignore file:
>
> - `core.ignore` patterns, that are effective in the same directory as the ignore file; and
> - `core.ignore.recursive` patterns that affect items in all of the directories below the .jazzignore file.